# How can I create group of objects to store information?

Tags: python, django

I have two models Pigeons and Treatment. Every pigeon can have multiple treatment. I want to create some groups of pigeon like all pigeons, cock, female, squeakers and when I want to create a treatment to select the group and assign the medication.

```
#models
class Pigeons(models.Model):
    ring= models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(PigeonStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    ......

class Treatment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True) 

    # we can treat only one pigeon

    pigeon = models.ManyToManyField(Pigeons, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # or select group to assign medication

    group = ......
    medication = models.ForeignKey(Medication, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Which is the best approach to do this? I have to create a separate model that store groups or it can be in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide the best approach for your project.  The two most common approaches would be to use a ForeignKey

```
group = models.ForeignKey(Sex, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

OR to use choices

```
SEX_OPTIONS = (
    ('male','Male'),
    ('female',Female')
)

group = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=SEX_OPTIONS)
```

Comment: And when I want to see all treatment for a pigeon, it include the treatments save with this approach? And this is for group based on sex, but how can I group all pigeon?

Comment: Treatment would be a separate model or choice.  I don't know why they would be included within the sex but I don't know what you're trying to achieve overall

Comment: Yes, it is a separate model. We supposed that I must create a vaccination list or give same medication to all pigeon in database. How can I do that rather than select every pigeon or how can I make a collective treatment? The treatment model has pigeon field that is a manytomanyfield, it means that I must select manually every pigeon but if I have 100 pigeon or more?